# MySQL Group-By query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following working MySQL script:

```
SELECT CAT.LCDescript as Category, 
       Labor.CAT, 
       Labor.LabDescript As Task, 
       ProjLab.PLqty As Qty,
       ProjLab.Plucost As UnitCost, 
       ProjLab.PLqty*ProjLab.Plucost as TotalCost
FROM `ProjLab` 
INNER JOIN Labor ON ProjLab.Lid = Labor.Lid
INNER JOIN CAT ON Labor.CAT = CAT.LCid
WHERE Pid=1
ORDER BY Category, Task ASC
```

It gives me a correct list of tasks by Category description and Task Description.
I would like to see totals for each category of "TotalCost" as well as summary total. Tried adding Group By Category but that fails. Do I need to add Group By Category after Where but this just gave me one line for each Category. Yes, I know that's probably what its supposed to do but I wanted all records AND the summary by category and ideally overall cost at end? Possible?

Comment: update your question add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you want a sum by TotalCost you need  a group by and sum but in this case you should not select value for qty and unitCost
or use an aggregated  function for these columns too

```
    SELECT CAT.LCDescript as Category, 
           Labor.CAT, 
           Labor.LabDescript As Task, 
           sum(ProjLab.PLqty*ProjLab.Plucost ) as TotalCost
    FROM `ProjLab` 
    INNER JOIN Labor ON ProjLab.Lid = Labor.Lid
    INNER JOIN CAT ON Labor.CAT = CAT.LCid
    WHERE Pid=1
    GROUP BY Category, Labor.CAT,Task   
    ORDER BY Category, Task ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks csaisEdge. That gave me part of solution with sum(qty*unitprice). I wanted the total of each category and also the overall total, as well as the individual records from 'ProjLab'. I tried using the "WITH ROLLUP" but I kept getting syntax error. So I ended up using two UNIONS, one for the catergory subtotals and one for the overall total as shown below. There is no doubt a much better solution, perhaps "WITH ROLLUP"??

```
-- this part gives all Projlab records
SELECT CAT.LCDescript Category, 
       Labor.LabDescript Task, 
       ProjLab.PLqty Qty,
       ProjLab.Plucost UnitCost,
       sum(ProjLab.PLqty*ProjLab.Plucost ) as TotalCost
FROM `ProjLab` 
INNER JOIN Labor ON ProjLab.Lid = Labor.Lid
INNER JOIN CAT ON Labor.CAT = CAT.LCid
WHERE Pid=1
GROUP BY Category, Task  
UNION
-- this part adds the category totals
SELECT CAT.LCDescript Category, 
       "_total" Task, 
       ProjLab.PLqty Qty,
       ProjLab.Plucost UnitCost,
       sum(ProjLab.PLqty*ProjLab.Plucost ) as TotalCost
FROM `ProjLab` 
INNER JOIN Labor ON ProjLab.Lid = Labor.Lid
INNER JOIN CAT ON Labor.CAT = CAT.LCid
WHERE Pid=1
GROUP BY Category 
UNION
-- this part give the grand total
SELECT  "__ total" AS Category, 
       "__" Task, 
       "__"  Qty,
       "__"  UnitCost,
       sum(ProjLab.PLqty*ProjLab.Plucost ) as TotalCost
FROM `ProjLab` 
INNER JOIN Labor ON ProjLab.Lid = Labor.Lid
INNER JOIN CAT ON Labor.CAT = CAT.LCid
WHERE Pid=1
GROUP BY Category 
ORDER BY Category, Task ASC
```